# Capybara won't fill in fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am new to Capybara (using 2.1.0) and I cannot get it to fill in some fields in my brand-new (Rails 4/Ruby 2) application. Since it's just started, the app is simple.

For my User#new, I fill in the one field, which has a validation, and it saves when it's valid and fails when it's not. Great. I have another model, and try to do CoiReport#new and it does not work.

It keeps failing with "Owner cannot be empty" (it's got a validate_presence_of validator) even though if I save_and_open_page before click_button "Create New" the field is filled in. The field is an  field, so I thought that might be it, but even when I changed it to type="text" it still fails. It also works when I do it by hand.

So both of these are very simple forms, but one works and one doesn't and I can't think what the difference is!

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for(@coi_record) do |f| %>
  <% if @coi_record.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@coi_record.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this coi_record from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @coi_record.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :owner_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :owner_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :signer_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :signer_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :signed_at %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :signed_at %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :is_current %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :is_current %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :has_no_conflicts %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :has_no_conflicts %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's the test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'test2' do
  it "should work!" do

    visit '/coi_records/new'
    page.should have_content('New coi_record')
    within '#new_coi_record' do
      fill_in 'Owner', :with => '1'
      check 'Is current'
      check 'Has no conflicts'
      click_button 'Create Coi record'
    end
    # save_and_open_page  
    page.should have_content('Coi record was successfully created.')
  end
end
```

Help!

Comment: This doesn't smell like a Capybara problem to me. Can you try to debug the `@coi_record` and check its state right before the `@coi_record.save` line in your controller?

Comment: Added <p><%= p @coi_record %></p> to the view. Running the spec I see two outputs, one for its first hit to the page, the second for when it fails to save and redisplays the page for editing. In the second case Owner == 1, as it should, and which should allow it to pass the validation.
#<CoiRecord id: nil, owner_id: nil, signer_id: nil, signed_at: nil, is_current: nil, has_no_conflicts: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
#<CoiRecord id: nil, owner_id: 1, signer_id: nil, signed_at: "2013-09-06 12:25:00", is_current: true, has_no_conflicts: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was simple pilot error on my part. depa was absolutely correct that this was *not* a Capybara problem. The problem was with my validator. CoiRecord is associated with User thusly:

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

I wanted this to be a required relation, so I had the validation, in CoiRecord, as

```
validates_presence_of :owner
```

where it should be

```
validates_presence_of :owner_id
```

Changing that lets the test pass. Rookie error. How embarrassing! Of course I looked at it 100 times and could not see it. depa pointed the way, as I could **see** the value was being set, so I had to wonder, why would the validation fail anyway...?

Though it would have been nice if Rails had noticed and reported the requirement of a field that doesn't exist...?

Comment: That's cool. You can accept your own answer now so other people will know the issue has been resolved.